# why the java applet jumps out of web broswer?

Tags: java, applet, popup, embed

I'm very new to Java , I have embedded a Java applet in an html/jsp file and launch it with tomcat.
The problem is the browser launches a Java applet window (like a pop-out windows) while I strictly want the applet to run inside the browser.

This is my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <APPLET archive="chat.jar" code="myApplet.class"
                codebase="http://localhost:8080/"
                width="0" height="0">
    </APPLET>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Why it jumps out?
2. How can I keep it running inside?

Comment: width(0) and height(0) in here may be not equal defined in-class. Try 800 600

Comment: tried that! still jumps out ! one thing ,it says (Note that an unsigned applet can only connect to the same server from whence it came)  also.. I don't care about this error ,it's just a change of ports or something like that..does it have anything  to do with it popping out?

Comment: You wrote BvcseApplet.java ?

Comment: not actually ...I found the code somewhere and did put my applets name there !

Comment: There  could be some code that spawns a new frame.

Comment: but since it's an applet shouldn't it run inside browser ? what code can possibly make an applet in a window outside the browser?

Comment: Applet has its own window, may have codes to create more frames such as a separate game-engine window, even can focus on the other frame and get in full-screen mode just as a fps game.

Comment: Maybe that applet has a main(String [] arg) to initialize a new instance in another frame.

Comment: alright, i'm gonna check ..thanks

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (of the applet code).